# How to get mongrel working with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, mongrel, bundler

Transitioning to bundler with an existing production setup. Naively with a gemfile and setup like:

```
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
gem "mongrel", git: "http://github.com/dynamix/mongrel.git"

bundle install --path /mnt/app/shared/bundle
```

Starting with

```
bundle exec mongrel_rails start --environment=production ...
```

results in

```
/mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:166:in `require': 
no such file to load -- /mnt/services/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/mongrel/init.rb (MissingSourceFile)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own, since I couldn't find a correct solution elsewhere on the web for this scenario:

The problem seems to be an interaction of `bundler` and `mongrel`'s use of the `gem_plugin`.  Yes, these may be on life support but unfortunately lots of people's production configs still depend on them.

Seems that with `mongrel --pre` installed from the `git` source, it's looking in `bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongrel_` instead of `bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongrel_` which is where `bundler` is stashing the gem cloned from `git`.

So the solution that worked for our config is to just symlink them:

```
ln -s /mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundle/gems/mongrel* \
 /mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.beta.1
```

This is clearly something simple that bundler could do automatically.  Full trace of the exception was:

```
/mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:166:in `require':
 no such file to load -- /mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/mongrel/init.rb (MissingSourceFile)
    from /mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:166:in `require'
    from /mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:134:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:241:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:241:in `each'
    from /mnt/services/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:112:in `load'
    from /mnt/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongrel-f3e69eb8e6fb/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:231:in `load_plugins'
```